# Count is zero after assigning to List

Tags: c#, list

I have the following code in my program:

```
List<_Transaction> transactionListing = collectionRun.AttachedTransactions;
```

When I debug, the AttachedTransactions hsa a count of 3 (its also a list of List<_Transaction>). But the assignment does not work because the transactionListing has a count of zero.
I'm perplexed.

EDIT: 
On the right hand side the count of AttachedTransactions is 3. But on the left hand side the count of transactionListing remains zero after assignment

Comment: **What** doesn't work? **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: So are we. We don't have enough information to help you I'm afraid.

Comment: What is `collectionRun.AttachedTransactions´? Type, definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<_Transaction> transactionListing = collectionRun.AttachedTransactions.ToList();
```

Or:

```
List<_Transaction> transactionListing = new List<_Transaction>(collectionRun.AttachedTransactions);
```

This will make a copy of the `AttachedTransactions` list at the time of assignment.

At the moment you're getting a reference to `collectionRun.AttachedTransactions` and I'm guessing that something else is altering it so it appears that the assignment isn't working.

Comment: Both of your methods create new lists. So in case that author wanted to assign a reference of collectionRun.AttachedTransactions to transactionListing it is not a solution.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly I tried the above but its still not working. I honestly have no idea whats happening.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the `collectionRun.AttachedTransactions` in the question. The type, the code before and after assignment, the `collectionRun` class etc

Comment: @RagtimeWilly I figured it out. It was the code AFTER the assignment, just like you said.